# Reshaping data based on different columns

Tags: r, reshape2, tidyr

I have this dataset called 'inputdata'

```
Country Unknown Male Female Affected Male Female Unaffected Male Female
USA      200  120   80     130     80    50     70        40    30
AU       140  80    60     60      30    30     80        50    30
```

And I will have two output data sets and it will be like the below ones, as you can see, the input dataset has 3 categories in here as mentioned in the column names 2,5,8.

In the output 1 dataset, Category column has categories which is the column names in input data. Then the country from country column and Male column will have value from Male column in the input.

Similarly in the output 2 dataset, Category and Country remains the same, but the 3rd column Actuals should have value from the corresponding categories in input, columns 2,5,8.

Key here is that the input dataset structure remains same.

```
Output 1

Category    Country Male 
Unknown      USA     120  
Affected     USA     80
Unaffected   USA     40
.
.
.

Output 2

Category    Country Actuals
Unknown      USA     200   
Affected     USA     130 
Unaffected   USA     70 
.
.
.
```

So what I did now is, using a for loop to subset every category from the input dataset using the indexes --

For example, using `inputdata[,c(1,i)]` and my `'i'` variable will be `3,6,9 for output 1` and `2,5,8 for output 2`. Then created a list of data frames ( one for each category) and combined them together for each outputs. I am just wondering if there is any other way I could do this to make it efficient.

EDIT :- Adding my code as requested,

```
for(i in seq(3, 9, by=3)) {
    if(!exists('mylist')) mylist <- NULL
    output1 <- inputdata[,c(1,i)]
    if(i==3) {
      output1$category <- 'unknown'
    } else if (i==6) {
      output1$category <- 'affected'
    } else
      output1$category <- 'unaffected'
    mylist <- c(mylist,output1)
    rm(output1)
  }


   for(i in seq(2, 8, by=3)) {
        if(!exists('mylist')) mylist <- NULL
        output2 <- inputdata[,c(1,i)]
        if(i==3) {
          output2$category <- 'unknown'
        } else if (i==6) {
          output2$category <- 'affected'
        } else
          output2$category <- 'unaffected'
        mylist <- c(mylist,output2)
        rm(output2)
      }
```

Please let me know if there is anything unclear.

Comment: Please post the code that you tried.

Comment: Added it here. :)

Comment: But you have columns with the same name. Column names must be unique. Can you load that table in R as a data.frame keeping those column names?

Comment: Yes I did. R allows reading it from excel that way using read_excel function.

Comment: We can even rename it to male1, male2, female1,female2 after reading it to R. That's not a problem.

Comment: Yes, but how can we know what is what? What are the different columns named female? And the different male ones?

Comment: Why wouldn't you want both Male(or female) & Actual Values in the same data frame?

Comment: Yeah. We can also have both in same dataset. Then I will subset them for my use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a base R method that uses `stack` to convert to long based on specific columns (i.e. male/female, category).

```
#data frame of categories - You can further split of country if needed 
# by split(d1, d1$country)

d1 <- data.frame(stack(df[-1][c(T, F, F)]), country = df$Country, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#  values        ind country
#1    200    Unknown     USA
#2    140    Unknown      AU
#3    130   Affected     USA
#4     60   Affected      AU
#5     70 Unaffected     USA
#6     80 Unaffected      AU

#create a list with two data frames (male and female)
#To split by country again, then lapply(l1, function(i) split(i, i$country))

l1 <- lapply(c('Male', 'Female'), function(i) setNames(data.frame(d1$ind, 
                                                 stack(df[grepl(i, names(df))])[-2],
                                                    df$Country, stringsAsFactors = F), 
                                              c('category', i, 'country')))

#[[1]]
#    category Male country
#1    Unknown  120     USA
#2    Unknown   80      AU
#3   Affected   80     USA
#4   Affected   30      AU
#5 Unaffected   40     USA
#6 Unaffected   50      AU

#[[2]]
#    category Female country
#1    Unknown     80     USA
#2    Unknown     60      AU
#3   Affected     50     USA
#4   Affected     30      AU
#5 Unaffected     30     USA
#6 Unaffected     30      AU
```

**DATA**

```
dput(df)
structure(list(Country = c("USA", "AU"), Unknown = c(200L, 140L
), Male = c(120L, 80L), Female = c(80L, 60L), Affected = c(130L, 
60L), Male.1 = c(80L, 30L), Female.1 = c(50L, 30L), Unaffected = c(70L, 
80L), Male.2 = c(40L, 50L), Female.2 = c(30L, 30L)), .Names = c("Country", 
"Unknown", "Male", "Female", "Affected", "Male.1", "Female.1", 
"Unaffected", "Male.2", "Female.2"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```